# File not exists error but the file exists in the location in swift

Tags: xcode, swift4, file-manager

```
    do {
        let filePath = "/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/Automation/demo1/test1.txt"
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        if (fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath))
        {
            try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: filePath, toPath: "/Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/Automation/")
        }
        else
        {
            print("File does not exist")
        }
    }
    catch let error as NSError 
    {
        print("Ooops! Something went wrong: \(error)")
    }
```

In above code i am getting "File does not exist " but i am 100% sure that file exists in that location.

Is there anything i am doing wrong?

Comment: Copy the value of your `filePath` to the clipboard, then in a terminal paste that as the argument to `ls`.

Comment: @Chris Yes i have done that and the file is present in that folder.

Comment: Is the app running as the same user as the home directory that you're trying to read belongs to?

Comment: No,App is running in an different directory and it reading from different directory.But it should be fine i guess. I have been using this code for different applications and it is working fine. @Chris

Comment: It looks like a users / permissions problem to me. If `xxxxx` is a different user and any of the directories in the path doesn't have the executable bit set, `FileManager` will report the file as not existing, since it can't get to it.

Comment: On checking for permission at level [xxxxx], I get "drwxrwxrwx+", which means that permission is not the problem.

Comment: And at `Desktop`, `Automation` and `demo1`?

Comment: So, I changed the code to just check if "/Users" exist or not, yet it is returning false.

Do you suggest that I chmod and give permission to all the directories in the path and check?

Comment: Certainly never all the way up to `/Users`, or even `/Users/xxxxx`. Given that `/Users` is reported as not existing I'm going to suggest Sandbox rules are getting in your way (but I have no experience of Sandbox rules).

Comment: No problem @Chris. i will look into sandbox rules, anyway Thank you for your suggestions.